# Migrating embedded SQL to LinqToSql vs stored procedure

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I am migrating some code from ColdFusion to .NET LinqToSQL. The following query is currently embedded into ColdFusion. Rather than trying to get LinqToSQL to this, I am considering writing a stored procedure. Note: the ## in CF in this context is really a # in SQL. I am not creating a global temp table

```
<cfquery name="qryTrafficDetails">
    DECLARE @startDate date
    DECLARE @endDate date
    SET     @startDate = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_date" value="#filter.StartDate#">
    SET     @endDate = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_date" value="#filter.endDate#">


    SELECT  CONVERT(date, CreateDate) AS CreateDate, url_vars.value('(search)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS Item, remote_addr
    INTO    ##tempTraffic
    FROM    dbo.Traffic WITH (NOLOCK)

    WHERE   Createdate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    AND     url_vars.exist('.[search]') = 1     


    SELECT Area, AreaSort, Item, CalendarDate, isNull(Visitor, 0) AS Visitor, ISNULL(Hit,0) AS Hit
    FROM    dbo.Calendar LEFT JOIN 
        (



        SELECT AreaSort = 10, 'Search' AS Area, FullGrid.Item AS Item, FullGrid.CalendarDate AS CreateDate,

                COUNT(DISTINCT remote_addr) AS visitor, 
                COUNT(remote_addr) as hit

        FROM  (
            SELECT DISTINCT CalendarDate, Item
            FROM dbo.Calendar, ##TempTraffic
            WHERE   CalendarDate  BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
            ) FullGrid 

        LEFT JOIN ##TempTraffic AS DataItem
            ON FullGrid.CalendarDate = CreateDate
            AND FullGrid.Item = DataItem.Item       

        GROUP BY FullGrid.Item, FullGrid.CalendarDate



        ) AS SummaryDetail

    ON  CalendarDate = SummaryDetail.CreateDate

    WHERE   CalendarDate  BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    AND AreaSort IS NOT NULL    

    ORDER BY AreaSort, Item, CalendarDate
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn qryTrafficDetails>
```

Some of the issues I am concerned with are:

- How to deal with temp tables
- Does LinqToSql cover everything?
- Is this an example of where LinqToSql is not appropriate?
- Performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure about the intentions and motivations of your sql code but seems to be a summary report. In this case probably linq to sql is not the ideal solution.

I don't think that you can create temp table from linq 2 sql. You can create sub query or maybe you can use linq 2 object to join the results of previously executed query.

But my suggestion is to check if there isn't a better way to query your data using a more concise query that can be executed also on linq 2 sql.

If you really need this kind of query probably it's better to put it in a stored procedure.